# Getting Error "invalid secret string" by running wp-cron.php manually

Tags: wp-cron

I am trying to run the wp-cron.php manually by calling it that way:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

Disabling the auto cron function with :

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', TRUE);
```

produces the same error.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The question we have to ask upfront: "Why are you calling it manually?".

Comment: Is "invalid secret string" the exact (!) error message? If so, the error isn't caused by WordPress. And what is the parameter "?doing_wp_cron" for?

Answer (score 2):

If you're launching wp-cron manually you don't need the "doing_wp_cron" parameter. The fact that you have it and haven't given it a value is very likely to be what's causing your error.

Answer (score 2):

Edit wp-config.php and add the secret key. A good spot is right after the Authentication Unique Keys and Salts. Please be sure to update the secret to be your own.

```
define( 'WP_CRON_CONTROL_SECRET', 'qUhYNCrdHSHOPwPgrdyY19yi0' );
```

Then you can run

```
http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron&qUhYNCrdHSHOPwPgrdyY19yi0
```

Where the part after the & is the secret key which you created with the define statement in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

For others with this issue, make sure you don't have a plugin like [WP-Cron Control](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-cron-control) enabled ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190303192209/https://imakeinternet.com/2017/02/22/web-development/wordpress/wordpress-tips-and-tricks/fix-wordpress-cron-error-invalid-secret-string/)).